# Perfect squares with two variables.

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Find all positive integers m, n such that $6^m + 2^n + 2$ is a perfect square. 
I've tried keeping a constant value of m and finding out n. 
Eg:

$m=1, n=0$

$m=1, n=3$

Comment: Here is a hint: Unless $m= 0$ or $n= 0$ then $6^m + 2^n + 2$ is even so if it is a square it is a square of an even number.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717598/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-22-25-2n-is-a-perfect-square), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209951/how-to-find-all-positive-integers-m-n-such-that-3m4n-is-a-perfect-square), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553419/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-282122n-is-a-perfect-square).

Comment: Another hint : If $m>1$ and $n>1$ , the number is of the form $4k+2$ , hence not a perfect square. Usually $0$ is not considered positive.

Answer (score 0):

As people in the comments mentioned, if $m > 1$ and $n > 1$ than our number divide $2$, but not divide $4$, so it cant be square. So the only cases are:

$1$) $m = 1$
In this case we have equation $2^n + 8$ is a perfect square. But if $n > 3$ than this number divide $8$, but not divide $16$, so it cant be square. So just consider $n = {1,2,3}$

$2$) $n = 1$
In this case we have equation $6^m + 4$ is a perfect square. But $6^m + 4 \equiv$  $3\ or \ 5\ (mod\ 7)$ which is not quadratic residue.

Thats all cases.

Comment: Numbers are positive integers or non-negative?

Comment: If you need non-negative integers than:

1) $m = 0\\$.

$2^n+3 \equiv 3 \ (mod\ 4)$ which in not quadratic residue.

2)$n = 0\\$

$6^m+3$ is square. If $m>1$ than this equation divide $3$, but not divide $9$, so it cant be square. Than just consider $m=0\ or\ 1$

Comment: I needed the postive integers only. Thank you so much.

Comment: In Case 1, shouldn't we show that when a number is divisible by a prime but not by the prime square, then it is not a perfect square? However, you've shown that it is divisible by "8" but not by 16. Shouldn't it be 4 instead of 8 as the square of 4 is 16? Also, 4 is not a prime number. So is the case still justified considering I cannot find any n>3?

Comment: I showed that the number is divisible $2^3$, but not divisible by $2^4$, so it cant be square, because if the number is square than every prime that divide our square has even power.